# ListView Java android

Tags: android, listactivity

I want to add KEY_TITLE, KEY_AUTHOR, KEY_THUMBNAIL, but when i compile in simulator android, why the result show like this?, only show KEY_TITLE, this my code :

```
JSONArray jsonPosts = mBlogData.getJSONArray("posts");
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> blogPosts = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

for(int i = 0 ; i < jsonPosts.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject post = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
    String titles = post.getString(KEY_TITLE);
    titles = Html.fromHtml(titles).toString();
    String author = post.getString(KEY_AUTHOR);
    author = Html.fromHtml(titles).toString();
    String thumbnail = post.getString(KEY_THUMBNAIL);
    thumbnail = Html.fromHtml(titles).toString();
    HashMap<String, String> blogPost = new HashMap<String, String>();
    blogPost.put(KEY_TITLE, titles);
    blogPost.put(KEY_AUTHOR, author);
    blogPost.put(KEY_THUMBNAIL, thumbnail);
    blogPosts.add(blogPost);
}

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MyClaimActivity.this, blogPosts, R.layout.activity_list, new String[] { KEY_TITLE, KEY_AUTHOR, KEY_THUMBNAIL }, new int[]{R.id.title, R.id.author,R.id.thumbnail});
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Why is the result like this?

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: What did you want it to be like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String titles = post.getString(KEY_TITLE);
titles = Html.fromHtml(titles).toString();
String author = post.getString(KEY_AUTHOR);
author = Html.fromHtml(titles).toString();
String thumbnail = post.getString(KEY_THUMBNAIL);
thumbnail = Html.fromHtml(titles).toString();
```

must change to

```
String titles = post.getString(KEY_TITLE);
titles = Html.fromHtml(titles).toString();
String author = post.getString(KEY_AUTHOR);
author = Html.fromHtml(author ).toString();
String thumbnail = post.getString(KEY_THUMBNAIL);
thumbnail = Html.fromHtml(thumbnail ).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `titles` repeatedly. Possibly a wrong copy/paste. You should fix it.

```
String author = post.getString(KEY_AUTHOR);
author = Html.fromHtml(author).toString();
String thumbnail = post.getString(KEY_THUMBNAIL);
thumbnail = Html.fromHtml(thumbnail).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You did a silly mistake. You are using `titles` for author and thumbnail too.

Change these lines

```
 author = Html.fromHtml(titles).toString();
 thumbnail = Html.fromHtml(titles).toString();
```

to

```
 author = Html.fromHtml(author).toString();
 thumbnail = Html.fromHtml(thumbnail).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is copy paste problem...you are taking the titles every time.

Use this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < jsonPosts.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject post = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
    String titles = post.getString(KEY_TITLE);
    titles = Html.fromHtml(titles).toString();
    String author = post.getString(KEY_AUTHOR);
    author = Html.fromHtml(author).toString();
    String thumbnail = post.getString(KEY_THUMBNAIL);
    thumbnail = Html.fromHtml(thumbnail).toString();
    HashMap<String, String> blogPost = new HashMap<String, String>();
    blogPost.put(KEY_TITLE, titles);
    blogPost.put(KEY_AUTHOR, author);
    blogPost.put(KEY_THUMBNAIL, thumbnail);
    blogPosts.add(blogPost);
}
```